# Address shown is real address or logical address

Tags: memory-management, memory-address

When we print the address of variable does it represent the actual physical address or logical address ..

In debug mode (visual studio) same address is shown repeatedly .

Comment: Neither. It's the virtual address.

Answer (score 0):

When you print the address of a variable it is always the virtual address.

Physical memory is abstracted away from you at a low level in your operating system, during normal operation users and developers will seldom ever be concerned with physical memory.

Learn more about [virtual memory from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory)